# regular expression in PHP to create wiki-style links

Tags: php, regex

I'm developing a site which is going to use wiki-style links to internal content eg [[Page Name]]

I'm trying to write a regex to achieve this and I've got as far as turning it into a link and replacing spaces with dashes (this is our space substitute rather than underscores) but only for page names of two words.

I could write a separate regex for all likely numbers of words (say from 10 downwards) but I'm sure there must be a neater way of doing it.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
$regex = "#[\[][\[]([^\s\]]*)[\s]([^\s\]]*)[\]][\]]#";
$description = preg_replace($regex,"<a href=\"/$1-$2\">$1 $2</a>",$description);
```

If someone can advise me how I can modify this regex so it works for any number of words that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://it.php.net/preg_replace_callback) function which accepts a callback to process the replacement string. You can also use [lazy quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) in the pattern instead of a lot of negations inside character classes.

The external `preg_replace_callback` will extract the matched text and pass it to the callback function, which will return the properly modified version.

```
$str = '[[Page Name with many words]]';

echo preg_replace_callback('/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/', 'parse_tags', $str);

function parse_tags($match) {
    $text = $match[1];
    $slug = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $text);
    return "<a href=\"$slug\">$text</a>";
}
```

Comment: You don't have to escape the closing brackets; `\[\[...]]` is perfectly valid

Answer (score 1):

You should use a callback function to do the replacement (using [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)):

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\[\[([^\]]+)\]\]/', function($matches) {
    return '<a href="' . preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $matches[1]) . '>' . $matches[1] . '</a>';
}, $str);
```

Comment: It is worth noting that anonymous functions won't work in PHP < 5.3.0